# What is the life cycle of a Smalltalk class?

Tags: smalltalk

I'd like to know what is the life cycle of a class (or object), I mean, when it gets into memory and is alive answering messages until finally gets removed from memory.

My assumptions are:

- Since you send messages to objects and classes, they must be alive and in memory to answer them
- You make an object alive (thus getting into memory and listening to messages) when you instantiate it by sending a 'new' messages to its class

Ok, so an object is alive from its instantiation until garbage collection kills it or you send it a destroy message (or maybe its class)

But, how you instantiate a class to make it alive?  you cannot send a NEW message to a kind of metaclass (and if so, what is the metametaclass to instantiate a metaclass?)  So, are classes alive by default?  Every class in smalltalk library is loaded into memory when you load an image? is really a lot of classes in memory at any time?  if so, how can I see classes and objects in memory in certain moment in time?

Comment: Most OO languages do just load classes when the definition is encountered. Classes to that extent are global objects. How explicit a language makes that depends on the language. Most languages have class methods just as they have instance methods, and `new` is one.

Answer (score 7):

As Leandro and Bert have described, you can send `new` to metaclass. The circular references this creates are somewhat difficult to think about, but they represent a "simplicity" and "elegance" of design and implementation (where beauty is in the eye of the beholder!). I've included a drawing below that shows how this works. Note especially the cycle between `Metaclass` and `Metaclass class`.

- Q: So, are classes alive by default?
- A: Yes, if they exist in the image as objects then they are "alive."
- Q: Every class in smalltalk library is loaded into memory when you load an image? is really a lot of classes in memory at any time?
- A: Yes, every class in the image is in memory. Is that a lot? It may take a few megabytes; that is what is in a "base" image that you get from the dialect provider. Given the memory used by Chrome, Smalltalk is actually quite modest!
- Q: If so, how can I see classes and objects in memory in certain moment in time?
- A: The class hierarchy browser shows classes that are reachable from a selected root (typically the Smalltalk Dictionary). A lower-level alternative is to use `Metaclass allInstances`.

Note also that while most Smalltalks have ClassBuilder, not all do so (GemStone does not), and its properties and behavior can be folded into Behavior.

Additional questions:

- Q: What if I want a smaller image?
- A: There are various Pharo images available, some with less (no GUI) and some with more. You are also free to "unload" any unneeded packages and save your image. You can also start with a "minimal" image and load things that you need. Yes, this is different from C-based languages (and others) that start empty every time they are created. The primary practical effect is that you look for things in the image rather than looking for things outside the image. If you find that you are running in an environment where you are limited to 1-2 MB, then this might not be best for you. Smalltalk's strength is in programmer productivity. Assembly's strength is small size and speed. What problem are you trying to solve?
- Q: What is the pink square?
- A: Everything in the pink square has the name " class" appended to it. All the boxes in the pink square are instances of Metaclass (follow the green "is kind of" lines to the right).
- Q: Tell me more about inheritance.
- A: In any OO system, a class describes the properties and behaviors of an object. Inheritance means that properties and behaviors of a superclass are also part of the nature of the object. Person class inherits from ClassDescription directly through Object class and Class. Being an instance of Metaclass does not provide inheritance. Instead it provides a place where the class creation properties and behaviors are described. So, yes, Object is an instance of "Object class" (is kind of) which describes how to create instances of Object. And, no, Object is not a specialization of "Object class" (inherits from). Instances of Object do not know how to create instances of Object; that is the role of the Object class (factory).

[image]

Comment: So every class and object from every package in my image gets loaded into memory and keep running listening to messages during the smalltalk running session.

Comment: I find this very ineficient and resource eating, in my pharo there're a lot of packages each several classes, most of then I don't need at all, when I'm creating a console app I don't need all graphic classes and objects, same about specific classes to handle protocols or services.

Comment: Even I think it could be a problem when deploying web apps , I assume you have to deploy the full image and thus every web app will be a full image with a lot of classes don't really needed and also duplicated.

Comment: In the picture I assume green lines are "instance of" and blue lines are "specialized from" (hierarchy), does this mean Object is an instance of class "Object class" being at the same time the root of the hierarchy? if so, since "Object class" is a specialization of Class, don't should Object be also a specialization of "Object class" and thus not the root of hierarchy?

Comment: being "Person class" an instance of Metaclass means it has multiple inheritance from "Object class" and "ClassDescription" (through Metaclass) ?

Comment: what represents the pink squeare in the picture?

Comment: Also I find having all classes active is a kind of mess to locate things you are interested in,  Wouldn't be more useful to have a mechanism to load and unload certain classes or packages in order to have in memory (or in image) only that you are currently using?  something similar to import in java

Answer (score 5):

Every Smalltalk has a `ClassBuilder` class, whose instances have the purpose of creating new classes. A `ClassBuilder` does this by creating first the `Metaclass` for the class about to be built, sending the class message `#new` to `Metaclass`. Then it is the `Metaclass` just created the one that creates its sole instance using the primive `'New'`.

The reason for having a `ClassBuilder` is that classes not only are created, they may be modified. For example, a class may change its superclass with another, or keep it but change the shape of its instances or its own shape.

The `ClassBuilder` takes care of all the details, and also is responsible for recompiling instance or class methods when the shape changes. Note that a change in one class will impact all its subclasses, if any. So, all the tasks required for the class need also proceed in subclasses.

In addition, new classes need to be *installed*, in the sense that they must be included in the Smalltalk dictionary so to keep them both accessible and alive.

Note finally that in the case of a change in shape (which can be explicit or the consequence of changing the superclass with another), existing instances of the class must be migrated so to conform to the new shape. All these tasks make the process that runs behind the scenes non-trivial. However, you can follow it from the time you send the class definition message all the way down to the `'New`' primitive and to the migration of existing instances.

Regarding the way classes are garbage collected, well, there is nothing special here. Smalltalk doesn't have any destroy message. Objects that are no longer referenced become ready to be collected. Even objects which may still be referenced could be collected, as it is the case with two objects that reference each other but are not referenced from the "outside", i.e., (possibly indirectly) from any root.

The reason why classes are not (easily) GCed is because they are referenced from the `Smalltalk` dictionary, which is one of the roots of the system. Of course, you can manually remove a class, which means that it will be removed from the `Smalltalk` dictionary. In those cases the environment will assist the programmer into finding whether there are references to the `Association` binding the class name to the class object from other classes. The environment will also assist the programmer in checking whether the class about to be removed has instances or sublasses. Also, since every class knows its subclasses, classes are referenced from there, so the superclass needs to remove the class from its list of subclasses as part of the process of deleting the class.

**Addendum** (from the comments below)

**Q.** Who creates the `ClassBuilder` class?

**A.** This is one of the (many) bootstrapping problems that every Smalltalk dialect solves. Any Smalltalk is born from a kernel, i.e., a minimal set of classes and instances with just enough support for creating new classes. Depending on the dialect, `ClassBuilder` may belong or not in the kernel. If it doesn't, then you can still create classes by hand, as the only that is needed is to be able to send the `#new` message to `Metaclass`. Note however that `Metaclass` (the class) needs to be in the kernel for any of this to work. Also, when you save the image all the objects (including classes and methods, which are objects too), are saved to disk. Afterwards, when you load the image in memory, the very same objects are there, and any running processes (which are also Smalltalk objects) that were running at saving time, will resume where they were interrupted when the save operation took place. Note also that no object is "instantiated", they are just loaded from disk into memory in a copy (+ possible relocate) primitive operation. So, no `#new` is involved when you load the image as the objects are already there.

---

**Q.** How `ClassBuilder` gets instantiated itself?

**A.** You may think of it as built by hand and then saved in the image. So, the next time you load the image `ClassBuilder` (the class) will be available. Actually, the complexity of `ClassBuilder` may require several iterations. The system/runtime programmer may start by creating a very simple version of it, to be handled with care, and then use this incipient class to refine itself in further iterations.

---

**Q.** Is there a  `Metaclass` for every class?

**A.** Yes.

---

**Q.** Is there any book to learn about internals and implementation of Smalltalk?

**A.** Smalltalk-80 The Language and its Implementation (you can find it online)

Comment: From your reply I understand ClassBuilder is always "alive and running" and its responsability is to instantiate any other object/class. So I suppose the sequence of events when you first open a smalltalk image is, for every class or object in the image ClassBuilder loads it into memory and "run it" to be disposable to receive messages, further instantiation of objects involve 'new' messages to the necessary classes.

Comment: But then, how ClassBuilder gets instantiated itself?  The other possibility is what it's said in other comments, all classes and objects saved in an image are instantiated (aka loaded in memory and run) when you first load the image, including ClassBuilder.

Comment: Also you said ClassBuilder first creates a Metaclass for the class being created, and then this metaclass takes the responsability of create object instances by message new.  So is there a Metaclass for every class? or is there one and only Metaclass shared by all classes (kind of singleton)?

Comment: Is there any book to learn about internals and implementation of Smalltalk?

Comment: @pep Many thanks for your questions. I've added them to my answer.

Comment: @pep Also read the answers from Bert and and James. They provide additional insights into this topic.

Answer (score 4):

All the classes in a live Smalltalk system are objects. Some were created a long time ago when the system was bootstrapped (e.g. some objects in Squeak are more than 20 years old). The memory occupied by the objects is saved to disk as an "image" file and then resumed later when you "start" that image, but the objects aren't created over and over again.

This is unlike in most other programming systems where classes and objects are created from source code every time you run a program. In Smalltalk, the objects are live in memory. The System Browser shows you a textual view of all the class objects in the system. You can "file out" a textual representation of a class but that text is not the original source code. The original source lives in the class objects in memory.

To create a new class, you send a message to its superclass:

```
Object subclass: #NameOfClass
    instanceVariableNames: 'instVarName1 instVarName2'
    classVariableNames: 'ClassVarName1 ClassVarName2'
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'Kernel-Objects'
```

which you normally do by "accepting" this template in a browser window. This instructs the existing superclass (`Object` in this case) to create a new class. Leandro's answer goes into the details of that. But essentially it is sending `new` to `Metaclass` to create a new metaclass object, and then sending `new` to that metaclass to create the actual class object. You can see the result of that by sending the `class` message:

```
'abc' class. "=> String"
'abc' class class. "=> String class"
'abc' class class class. "=> Metaclass"
```

So in this case, `'abc'` is an instance of `String`, which is an instance of `String class`, which is an instance of `Metaclass`.

The `Metaclass` object itself is part of the base system and has been instantiated many many years ago (arguably in the early 1980ies).

The details of this are a little bit more complicated but this is a pretty good approximation of what is happening.

Comment: Ok, and is it the same for source text files based smalltalk like gnu smalltalk?